# a:link not filling whole td box

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

I have a table, and I wanted every cell to be clickable. This somewhat works, but it seems the link is not filling in the entire box, which becomes a problem when I apply a hover effect of someone clicks too close to the edge. Is there any way to fix this?

This is my css

```css
.dashboardMods td a {
  display: block;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

.dashboardMods td:hover{
  background-color:#4297c2;
}
```

[image: link not filling in box]

Comment: And your HTML would be..?

Comment: did you trying putting in the width and height in pixels instead of percent?

Comment: try adding `margin:0; padding:0; line-height:100%;`

Comment: Please provide the Complete code: You HTML of table and CSS for full table..

Comment: @user2719346 My table is too large to post and includes company data I cannot share. It is just a normal html table. You can google html table and see what it looks like.

Comment: @circle73 I have tried that, unfortunately that does not work, it just makes the link smaller.

Comment: @DavidThomas my html is way too long to be posted here and contains confidential information.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.dashboardMods td` will probably have a padding, which prevents the inner elements to grow larger then `width - (padding * 2)` because the padding is on both sides.

Also, `height: 100%` will not always work, depending on browser and HTML spec (quirksmode)

Comment: This unfortunately, did not work. The padding might be the issue, but stripping it or adding to it is not effecting the link positively. Stripping in makes the link shrink and adding makes it break out of the box. I al also trying to make this responsive so I don't want to set specific heights incase the link is more that that said weight or height.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `padding` from the `<td>`.  Instead you can add the same padding to the `<a>` for a similar effect.  Just to be certain you could also do `.dashboardMods a:hover` instead for changing the bg.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.dashboardMods td{
  padding:0;
}
.dashboardMods td a{
  display: block;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  line-height:100%;
}
```

Comment: This did not work, this only made the link a thin line instead of the entire block. I don't think this has anything to do with padding, I have stripped the padding from the td's previously. Sorry for not putting that earlier, didn't think of it. :)

Comment: can you create an example on jsfiddle?

Comment: try this: `.dashboardMods td a{ padding:100%; }`

Comment: I tried creating a fiddle, but I am having a bit of trouble because I'm working with tables inside of a bootstrap wrap and Ic cannot recreate the entire environment again. I tried adding the 100% padding and it made everything so huge that you couldn't even find the numbers. haha

Comment: hahahaha sorry about that!! i don't know if you're working locally in your machine, if you aren't maybe it is easier if you could give a link to the web page